# Слайдер div'ов на jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть несклько `div`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">1</div>
    <div class="block">2</div>
    <div class="block">3</div>
    <div class="block">4</div>
    <div class="block">5</div>
    <div class="block">6</div>
</div>
```

Сначала будут показываться только первые 3 дива, т.е. div 1, 2 и 3. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на `<div class="btn">` первый div скрывался, а 4 - появлялся. Т.е. это можно назвать как слайдер, только с дивами. Как это можно реализовать на jQuery?

Comment: Покажите код, или Ваши наработки, в противномслучае это подпадает под статью - решение за автора

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример реализации.

container надо обернуть в блок wrap, которому задать ширину, равную 3 div. Самому container задать ширину в 6 div. Таким образом, будут показаны только 3 первых div.

Теперь на кнопки надо повесить код, который будет вычислять margin-left для container и добавлять его к container. Так делаем прокрутку слайдера. Размер margin-left вычисляется как (номер левого div минус) * ширину div.

Чтобы понимать, где мы находимся, надо где-то хранить (номер левого div - 1). Для этого добавляем произвольный атрибут .data к contaner.

Доработать вычисления и css я предоставляю вам самому. Или можно взять готовый код с [одного из моих сайтов](https://houselit.ru/).

```js
$('.left').on('click', function() {
  var count = $('.container div').length;
  var columns = 3;
  var columnWidth = 100 / columns;

  if (count <= columns) return;

  var leftItem = $('.container').data('left item');
  if (typeof leftItem === "undefined") {
    leftItem = 0;
  }

  leftItem = leftItem - 1;
  if (leftItem < 0) leftItem = 0;
  $('.container').data('left item', leftItem);

  $('.container').css('margin-left', -columnWidth * leftItem + '%');

});

$('.right').on('click', function() {
  var count = $('.container div').length;
  var columns = 3;
  var columnWidth = 100 / columns;

  if (count <= columns) return;

  var leftItem = $('.container').data('left item');
  if (typeof leftItem === "undefined") {
    leftItem = 0;
  }

  leftItem = leftItem + 1;
  if ((leftItem + columns) > count) leftItem = count - columns;
  $('.container').data('left item', leftItem);

  $('.container').css('margin-left', -columnWidth * leftItem + '%');

});
```

```css
.container-wrap {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  display: block;
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block">1</div>
    <div class="block">2</div>
    <div class="block">3</div>
    <div class="block">4</div>
    <div class="block">5</div>
    <div class="block">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="left"> &lt; </div>
<div class="right"> &gt; </div>
```